# Re-inject content scripts after update

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which injects an iframe into every open tab. I have a chrome.runtime.onInstalled listener in my background.js which manually injects the required scripts as follows (Details of the API here : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled ) :

**background.js**

```
  var injectIframeInAllTabs = function(){
    console.log("reinject content scripts into all tabs");
    var manifest = chrome.app.getDetails();
    chrome.windows.getAll({},function(windows){
      for( var win in windows ){
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function reloadTabs(tabs) {
          for (var i in tabs) {
            var scripts = manifest.content_scripts[0].js;
            console.log("content scripts ", scripts);
            var k = 0, s = scripts.length;
            for( ; k < s; k++ ) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {
                file: scripts[k]
              });
            }

          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

This works fine when I first install the extension. I want to do the same when my extension is updated. If I run the same script on update as well, I do not see a new iframe injected. Not only that, if I try to send a message to my content script AFTER the update, none of the messages go through to the content script. I have seen other people also running into the same issue on SO ([Chrome: message content-script on runtime.onInstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454050/chrome-message-content-script-on-runtime-oninstalled)). What is the correct way of removing old content scripts and injecting new ones after chrome extension update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the extension is updated Chrome automatically cuts off all the "old" content scripts from talking to the background page and they also throw an exception if the old content script does try to communicate with the runtime. This was the missing piece for me. All I did was, in `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` in `bg.js`, I call the same method as posted in the question. That injects another iframe that talks to the correct runtime. At some point in time, the old content scripts tries to talk to the runtime which fails. I catch that exception and just wipeout the old content script. Also note that, each iframe gets injected into its own "isolated world" (Isolated world is explained here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laLudeUmXHM) hence newly injected iframe cannot clear out the old lingering iframe.

Hope this helps someone in future!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to "remove" old content scripts (Apart from reloading the page in question using window.location.reload, which would be bad)

If you want to be more flexible about what code you execute in your content script, use the "code" parameter in the executeScript function, that lets you pass in a raw string with javascript code. If your content script is just one big function (i.e. content_script_function) which lives in background.js

in *background.js*:

```
function content_script_function(relevant_background_script_info) {
   // this function will be serialized as a string using .toString()
   // and will be called in the context of the content script page
   // do your content script stuff here...
}

function execute_script_in_content_page(info) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid,
    {code: "(" + content_script_function.toString() + ")(" +
     JSON.stringify(info) + ");"});
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  execute_script_in_content_page.bind( { reason: 'onUpdated',
                                         otherinfo: chrome.app.getDetails() });

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(
  execute_script_in_content_page.bind( { reason: 'onInstalled',
                                         otherinfo: chrome.app.getDetails() });
)
```

Where relevant_background_script_info contains information about the background page, i.e. which version it is, whether there was an upgrade event, and why the function is being called. The content script page still maintains all its relevant state. This way you have full control over how to handle an "upgrade" event.

Comment: Thanks @kzahel, I can see that this might work. I will give it a shot but one more follow up question is : what if there're more changes in the content scripts themselves in the updated package? Just calling an "update" function on the content script will not suffice in that case. true?

Comment: Well. You define the definition of content_script_function in the background page, and the background page is the one calling .toString() on it, so when your extension updates, you will have the new definition available. This is the most flexible way to approach it. You can also inject at document_start and have your script run before any other script. Injecting with "code" parameter further guarantees this, as it runs as "synchronously"

Comment: Umm..I am still not sure. If I have the content script as a background script, how does the extension work on refresh where the browser tries to inject content scripts itself? Also, if I can executeScript after update, then can I not call the method that I have posted originally in the question when the extension is updated and that will take care of things correctly? I must be missing something, do you have an example of this by any chance? Thanks!